# Warning about function prototype even when the function takes arguments

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, function-prototypes

I have a simple function in C which takes `int*` argument and I have the declaration of it in the header file like this:

```
void mapAuditFioError(int *errno);
```

But compiler cirbs compiling the files including this header as follows:

```
"warning: function declaration isn't a prototype"
```

and also:

```
"warning: passing argument 1 of 'mapAuditFioError' from incompatible pointer type"
```

even though am invoking it with a integer pointer itself.

Browsing for this warning always talks about functions like this : `int func()` which should actually be declared as `int func(void)`. But what is the problem in my function above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [`errno`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h) is a [reserved name](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html) in C (free-standing implementations aside), used for communicating erroneous conditions from standard library functions. As the glibc documentation says:

> The names of all library types, macros, variables and functions that
>   come from the ISO C standard are reserved unconditionally; **your
>   program may not redefine these names**. All other library names are
>   reserved if your program explicitly includes the header file that
>   defines or declares them.

You cannot use `errno` as a variable name. It could be declared as a macro, and often it is.

For example on GCC and glibc on my Linux, if I include say `<stdio.h>` before the prototype,

```
void foo(int *errno);
```

is preprocessed into

```
void foo(int *(*__errno_location ()));
```

Now, that does compile without warnings because it is a legal construct; on your C compiler the `errno` behaves differently.

---

To fix it, call your parameter something else, such as `errcode` or `error_number`.

---

The C11 standard N1570 Committee Draft 7.5 on `<errno.h>` specifically says that

> If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, or a program
>   defines **an identifier** with the name
>   `errno`, the **behavior is undefined**.

Comment: To fix, call the parameter something other than `errno`

Comment: Should be "...if I include, say, `<errno.h>`...", I think. Afaik, `<stdio.h>` mustn't define `errno`.

Comment: @mafso all these names are reserved even if you did not include the headers that supposedly define these names.

Comment: As I read C11 (n1570) 7.1.3 p1, `errno` is always reserved for an identifier with external linkage, and for any use if an associated header is included (the only associated header should be `<errno.h>`). I'm not suggesting to use `errno` in the cases where it's technically allowed, but I think the example given here cannot be reproduced on any conforming implementation.

Comment: n1570 says: that it is **undefined** behaviour, if "a macro definition of
errno is suppressed in order to access an actual object, or the
program defines an identifier with the name errno (7.5)"

Comment: As I read it, this only applies if `<errno.h>` is included. Anyway, I think it would be bad for an implementation to define it in `<stdio.h>`, because you don't notice if you forget to include `<errno.h>`, and I think no implementation does (did you really try it as described in your answer?), and I think, a conforming implementation isn't allowed to.

Comment: No, it is specifically said that declaring an identifier named `errno` has undefined behaviour. It is not said that "declaring an identifier named `errno` when the header is included is undefined behaviour.

Comment: If this were the intent and what's described in 7.5 should apply also if `<errno.h>` wasn't included, mentioning it explicitly in 7.1.3 would be unnecessary. But I agree the wording seems not exactly clear. And I still doubt any implementation defines `errno` in `<stdio.h>`. But I don't think this question is relevant for practical purposes (nor that this answer really suffers from this error, if it is one), so I'm OK with letting the matter rest.

Comment: The code in my answer was from `gcc -E` output where I did include only `<stdio.h>` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I was worrying about every other thing for past few days and dint guess it can be the variable name !!!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I was not aware of that, accepted it now. Thanks.